# Deleted pages goes to Orphaned Pages in MediaWiki. How?

Tags: mediawiki

Recently I started working on MediaWiki. I noticed one thing that when particular dev team delete the page for their project from wiki it goes to Orphaned pages under Tools--->Special Pages.To investigate it I created a page and deleted it but it didn't go to the Orphaned pages.

Can someone have any idea how this is happening?I want that if someone delete the pages it should not go under Orphaned Pages.Are there any permission we need to set or some kind of settings we need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Deleted pages have nothing to do with orphaned pages. Orphaned pages are pages that are not linked from or transcluded into other pages in your wiki.

So there could be active (not deleted) orphaned pages too.

If another page links to an orphaned page it will disappear from https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:LonelyPages

Comment: If I know this page is not linked or transcluded into other pages in my wiki.How could I cleanup those from Orphaned pages?I have one more question how these pages come into the Orphaned?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't prevent pages from going onto the special page if they are not linked from other pages. I would suggest you create a dummy page where you link the pages you don't want to appear on the special page.